# Extract all numbers from braces with RegExp

Tags: javascript, java, regex

Let's assume i have a string:

```
 My things (123, 456, 678) are mine and there are 3 things
```

I want to extract all numbers from braces (in my example: **123**; **456**; **678**) with RegExp, but all yet I've done only is RegExp for fetching **(123, 456, 678)** as first group and **678** as second group and i don't know what else to do with it. See [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/tM8eZ4/1) for my example

Comment: You will need to parse the group for it's subparts. Also on regex101 make sure to set the flavor to javascript (if that is what you are using). A simpler regex also would be `\([\d, ]+\)`.

Comment: To get 123, 456, 789 (excluding brackets) you can use `\(([0-9, ]*)\)`

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
 (\d{3})\,.*(\d{3})\,.*(\d{3})
```

This matches every 3 digits, then separates into groups at every comma

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reply. No, it just extracts all in braces. For example, is matches (aaa), but it is not what i looking for. And secondly, i want also to split all content in braces to numbers

Comment: Sorry, didn't quite understand what you fully wanted. See my edit to see if that is correct

Comment: This won't work for an array of ints that have more than 3 digits and won't work for several digits. i.e. `(1,1234,56,789)`..

Comment: You are close, but i haven't restriction on number length and count of numbers. Numbers can have more than 3 digits as less than 3 digits. Also it can be more than 3 numbers in braces